# Index a document into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am trying to index some data by using below command from elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-working-with-elasticsearch.html:

curl -u USER:Password https://localhost:9200/my_index/_doc -XPOST -k 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
"title": "One", "tags": ["ruby"]
}'

but I am getting error:
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or maybe tell me about how to do indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Type header needs to be passed with -H not -k

```
curl -u USER:Password https://localhost:9200/my_index/_doc -XPOST -k -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "title": "One", "tags": ["ruby"] }'
                                                                     ^^
                                                                     ||
```

The rest is fine

Comment: but without -k it gives me  SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Comment: See my answer, `-k` is there, but you missed `-H`

Comment: curl -u USER:Password https://localhost:9200/my_index/_doc -XPOST -k -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "title": "One", "tags": ["ruby"] }'
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [USER] for REST request [/my_index/_doc]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [USER] for REST request [/my_index/_doc]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer

Comment: That's a different error now: `unable to authenticate user [USER]` The initial issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Try again without "-u" flag, because you already informed the user inside the url.